# Primefaces SlideMenu- change initial state

Tags: primefaces

We are using SlideMenu from primefaces (v3.5). Let's say there is a main menu and 2 sub menus. Is it possible to change the default view of the SlideMenu so that I see the 1st submenu always. Could someone help me on this?

Comment: Please paste your code, that how much you have tried. Based on that we can help you further.

Comment: Also, I would appreciate if you can attach your desired screen from PPT or somewhere to justify your requirement.